# Udemy Affiliate API - Authentication Error (403 Notice Array to string conversion)

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, php-curl

I'm trying to use the Udemy API with the correct answer from this Stackoverflow's post: [curl request in udemy api is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401577/curl-request-in-udemy-api-is-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$url = "https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses";
//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Udemy-Client-Id: xxx','X-Udemy-Client-Secret: xxx',"Authorization: base64 encoded value of client-id:client-secret","Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
echo curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

// Will dump a beauty json :3
echo $result = json_decode($result,true);
```

I have added my own client ID and secret ID and tested them on the Udemy sites getting a status 200.

The error I get from the code above is: 403 Notice Array to string conversion.

Can anyone sees what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $result = json_decode($result,true);
```

`json_decode()` turns the response (string containing a JSON) into an associative array.

You then pass the array to `echo` and this raises the error.

The fix:

```
echo $result; // `$result` is still a string (the response)
```

Then if you need to access the response as an associative array

```
$result = json_decode($result,true);
```